# Assigning an index to a constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I have a script written for Oracle databases that I'm converting to work in SQL Server and I have two questions about a specific section of code.

In **Oracle** script I have this code:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_PORTALROLES" ON "PORTAL_ROLE" ("ROLE_NAME");

ALTER TABLE "PORTAL_ROLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_PORTALROLES" 
      PRIMARY KEY ("ROLE_NAME") USING INDEX  ENABLE;
```

**Question (1)**

From the code above what is the `USING INDEX` command in the `ALTER TABLE` line doing? Is it assigning the `UNIQUE INDEX` created on the first line to the newly created `CONSTRAINT` or is the `CONSTRAINT` getting a new `UNIQUE INDEX` to use when it is created?

**Question (2)**

To duplicate this in SQL Server, I commented out the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` line like this:

```
--CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_PORTALROLES" ON "PORTAL_ROLE" ("ROLE_NAME");
```

And then replaced the `ALTER TABLE` line with this:

```
ALTER TABLE "PORTAL_ROLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_PORTALROLES" PRIMARY KEY ("ROLE_NAME");
```

I understand that when a `PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT` is created in SQL Server a `UNIQUE INDEX` is automatically made. So is the one line of SQL Server code directly above doing the same thing as the two lines of Oracle code above?

**EDIT**

One final question. Is there a way in Oracle and SQL Server to assign an existing `INDEX` to a `CONSTRAINT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, you can do

```
alter table PORTAL_ROLE add constraint pk_portalroles primary key('ROLE_NAME');
```

And it will create unique index for you. But when you drop or disable(!) constraint, it will drop that index. To avoid that (or to give index some custom name, or to use non-unique index, etc), it is usually done in 2 steps as in your code (as recommended by ORACLE).

Q1: constraint will be using existing index.

Q2: Yes, it will be enough for SQL Server.

> [When you specify a unique constraint on one or more columns, Oracle implicitly creates an index on the unique key. If you are defining uniqueness for purposes of query performance, then Oracle recommends that you instead create the unique index explicitly using a CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement. You can also use the CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement to create a unique function-based index that defines a conditional unique constraint.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52163)

Answer (score 2):

In **Oracle**

If there are more than one indexes on the column on which you want to add PK constraint, we can selectively choose the index to be assoicated with the PK using “USING INDEX“. This clause can be used while:

Adding the PK constraint for the first time (using “ALTER TABLE” command).

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_test ( col_1 NUMBER, 
                        col_2 NUMBER,
                        col_3 NUMBER);

CREATE INDEX idx_col_1_2 ON tbl_test(col_1, col_2);

CREATE INDEX idx_col_1_3 ON tbl_test(col_1, col_3);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_col_1 ON tbl_test(col_1);

-- Forcing oracle to use the unique index "IDX_COL_1"
ALTER TABLE tbl_test ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_test_pk PRIMARY KEY(col_1) 
USING INDEX idx_col_1;

SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type, index_name
  FROM user_constraints
 WHERE table_name = 'TBL_TEST';

-- CONSTRAINT_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | INDEX_NAME
-- TBL_TEST_PK     | P               | IDX_COL_1
```

What if? If you don't use the **USING INDEX** clause

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_test ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_test_pk PRIMARY KEY(col_1);
```

-- Although an unique index exists, oracle has picked up the first index

```
SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type, index_name
  FROM user_constraints
 WHERE table_name = 'TBL_TEST';

-- CONSTRAINT_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | INDEX_NAME
-- TBL_TEST_PK     | P               | IDX_COL_1_2
```

That shows **The index associated with the PK constraint needn’t be unique.**

But in SQLServer implicitly **CLUSTERED INDEX** will be created when primary key defined on any column

So to your last question. In Oracle you can assign index which we created can be assigned to constraints which we will create in future.
In SQLServer i guess it is not possible.

Comment: In SQL Server, the PK will be clustered only if the table doesn't already have a clustered index. If a table already has a clustered index, it will be preserved.